# Wordpress issue with if condition when using it inside Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, if-statement, post, pagination

am using if condition inside post loop to display only post have thumbnail ,it work just fine but the loop counting the hidden posts in pagination bar which haven't any thumbnail and pagination also keep giving me blank page for the hidden post how can i force the loop to counting just the result of if condition posts
here's my code

```
        <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => array('post','news','video'),
    );
    query_posts($args);
    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
       <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
    <?php }else{} ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best not to be returning results without thumbnails if you dont want them there.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', // only return results with thumbnail
    'post_type' => array('post','news','video'),
    );
    query_posts($args);

    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 

    if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
            echo get_the_title(); 
    }

    endwhile;

    wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav();
  ?>
```